# Show only half of SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I'm showing my SVG image in the card

```
  <div class="card-image">
    <img src="/images/linux.svg" />
  </div>
```

I couldn't upload the SVG file here, but what I'd like to do is: (After an event is triggered)

- Show the full original SVG in the beginning, but when an action is taken, only left or right half of the SVG image is shown in color, but the other half is in grayscale.
- I want to be able to adjust the rotation so that I can choose the angle at which the image is grayed out.

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a pseudo element on the container, and set a gradient to this pseudoelement that is transparent for half of it, a gray for the other half. The linear gradient can be set at the angle the you want

```css
.card-image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.grayed:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    background-image: linear-gradient(110deg, transparent 50%, #888a 50%);

}
```

```html
<div class="card-image">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
</div>
<div class="card-image grayed">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" />
</div>
```

```css
.card-image {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.grayed:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%; 
    height: 200%;
    left: 50%;
    top: -50%;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: white;
    mix-blend-mode: color;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform-origin: left center;
    animation: rotate infinite 10s linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from {     transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {     transform: rotate(360deg);}

}
```

```html
<div class="card-image grayed">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/600/400" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for a potential solution. I was looking for towards gray-scaling the paths rather than superimposing the images itself. I'm assuming it's not easily possible

Comment: Added another solution, this time making a gray-scale version of the image.

Comment: Happy that it helped !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to add linear gradients on images.

```
background-image:
linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(x, y , w, z ), rgba(a, b, c, d)),
url('image.jpg');
```

You could then use [javascript to modify the style in the class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style), this could allow you to change properties such as colors, however, I am not exactly sure which property would control where the gradient start, but it's a good pointer if you need one. If you can find a way to select where the gradient start (in relation to, an offset for example, or maybe specific height) you could then have it be black and white and use JS to modify the position/color.